# Pep-8 like style guidelines for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Is there a style guidelines document for JavaScript? Something like pep-8 for python or similar.

I could find http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines, so looking for things in a similar spirit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is quite a good one with JavaScript Code Quality Tool

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

and the instruction

[JSLint instruction](http://www.jslint.com/help.html)

but be careful it may hurt your feeling

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [JavaScript Naming Conventions](https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-naming-conventions/) page. It points out some things much better than **JSLint** and **JSLint instruction**.